# Problem with css richfaces (on seam)

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a problem with the css generated by richfaces. When I deploy my application with eclipse, sometimes I have css, sometimes not.

I have found that richfaces generate this file:

http://localhost:7001/myproject/a4j/s/3_3_3.Final/stylesheet/theme.xcss/DATB/eAF7sqpgb-jyGdIAFrMEaw__

And when this file is empty, I have none css on my page.

Why this file is empty sometimes ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: we also faced similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I have found a problem:

With firebug, if I change this url:

http://localhost:7001/myproject/a4j/s/3_3_3.Final/stylesheet/theme.xcss/DATB/eAF7sqpgb-jyGdIAFrMEaw__

By this:

http://localhost:7001/myproject/a4j/s/3_3_3.Final/stylesheet/theme.xcss

The css is ok, why richfaces add /DATB/eAF7sqpgb-jyGdIAFrMEaw__ in the url ?